# Can I add comments to a table or column using ActiveRecord Migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

In MySQL (and other SQL databases), it can be helpful to add comments to a table or column whose purpose may be unclear. (Search MySQL's [create table syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) for "comment" for examples.)

Is there a way to do this in an ActiveRecord Migration? I have tried this with no results.

```
create_table :stuff do |t|
  t.integer :obscure_column, :comment => "Explanatory comment"
end
```

I'm using Rails 3.1.

Comment: I wrote a gem not long ago `migration_comments` that will do what you need.  Hasn't been battle tested for long, but I'd welcome any input...

Comment: @PinnyM - Finally tried it out. Awesome! Thanks for releasing it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [migration_comments](https://github.com/pinnymz/migration_comments) gem mentioned in a comment to the original question appears to be the best cross-database solution for this need.  In addition to providing migrations support for adding table and column comments, the gem also annotates the schema.rb file to include all of the comments.  Perfect for my company's needs (large legacy rails app where the database model is ambiguous and also shared with a team of analysts writing native SQL reports).

Comment: It's worth noting that comments are baked in in Rails 5, no need for a gem. C.f. "comment" modifier http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers

Comment: In the latest rails, one can use `change_column_comment`, as explained in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60584476/3090068

Answer (score 9):

In Rails 5 you can use the `change_column`:

```rb
class AddCommentsToReferences < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    change_column :references, :achievement_id, :integer, comment: 'Achievement'
    change_column :references, :object_id, :integer, comment: 'Achievement object id'
  end
end
```

don't forget write correct column_type as third parameter.

Comment: In the latest rails, one can use `change_column_comment`, as explained in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60584476/3090068

Answer (score 5):

There is a gem called [pg_comment](https://github.com/albertosaurus/pg_comment) that will add this functionality if you are using postgresql.

The gem adds extra commands to add the comments. Note that the syntax in postgresql is different than in mysql, and I guess that is why there is no general ActiveRecord implementation.

For example:

```
create_table :stuff do |t|
  t.integer :some_value
end
set_table_comment :stuff, 'This table stores stuff.'
set_column_comment :stuff, :some_value, 'Stores some value'
```

This could get pretty verbose, but I know there are some nice tools that make use of this.

Secondly, Rails indeed allows you to manage your schema from within rails (and that is awesome), it may seem sufficient to document your migrations, but after a while nobody looks at the migrations anymore. And you are stuck with an undocumented schema.

In the [oracle-enhanced](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced) adapter this feature is available from the start, and has just the same syntax as you proposed.

Unfortunately I have not found a similar gem or solution for MySQL.

Comment: This one is for MySQL, but it hasn't been updated in 4 years: https://github.com/openrain/activerecord-comments

Answer (score 5):

I don't know when this method is introduced, but in the latest rails (6.0) you can use `change_column_comment` method.

```
def change
  change_column_comment(:posts, :state, from: "old_comment", to: "new_comment")
end
```

refer: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_comment

Comment: Was [introduced in Rails 5 as of January 3rd, 2016 per this PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c690b9ce39c893077b48fa5b27af87e995f97e9b), however was not made [public API until October 4th, 2017](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/85ca01bcb319d5ce66c0fa9ce6aede533492f0e9).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `change_column_comment` (already mentioned in another answer) there is `change_table_comment`:

```rb
change_table_comment(:posts, from: "old table comment", to: "new table comment")
```

The `from:` key allows you to create a reversible migration for the comment.  This will probably usually mean changing it from `nil` to some string.  You can of course remove a comment by changing it `to: nil`.